# How to get the quantity value to update when plus and minus buttons are clicked and their functions are called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, onclick

For the gift website which I'm working on, I am having difficulty getting the quantity to change using plus and minus buttons. There are multiple items being displayed on the page in a table so ideally I'd be able to change the quantity for each individually.

Within html script tags, I have inserted a JavaScript script containing functions to increment and decrement the value each time the corresponding button is pressed but when running the web app, nothing happens at all when the buttons are clicked

Below is the script in html:

```
<script>
var count = 1;
var countEl = document.getElementById("count");
function plus(){
    count++;
    countEl.value = count;
}
function minus(){
    if (count > 1) {
        count--;
        countEl.value = count;
    }
}
</script>
```

Below is the html code which includes the buttons:

```
 <c:forEach var = "row" items = "${result.rows}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value = "${row.gift_code}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value = "£${row.price}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value = "${row.stock}"/></td>
            <td><div id="outer">
                <div><button type="button" name="button"onclick="minus()"><img src="minus.jpg" alt="minus"/></button></div>
                <div><input type="text" name="name" value="1" size="10" id="count"></div>
                <div><button type="button" name="button"onclick="plus()"><img src="plus.jpg" alt="plus"/></button></div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form action="order.jsp" method="GET">
                    <input type = "hidden" name = "gift_code"
                           value = "${row.gift_code}" />
                    <input type = "hidden" name = "price"
                           value = "${row.price}" />
                    <input type = "submit" value = "Add to giftlist" />
                    <input type = "hidden" name = "stock"
                           value = "${row.stock}" />

                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </c:forEach>
```

Quantity should increase by 1 when the plus button is clicked and decrease by 1 when the minus button is clicked but the quantity currently remains the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and it worked well but it won't work with multiple inputs since you would be using the same variables. If your code doesn't work and your html is exactly like the on you posed, the issue might be in the link between your html and your javascript code. Do you have something like `<script src="myscripts.js"></script>` in your html ? This page might help you: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp

If not, here's an example that works with multiple inputs:

```js
function plus(elem){
    let targetElem = elem.parentNode.previousElementSibling.childNodes[0];
    let targetCount = parseInt(targetElem.value);
    targetCount++;
    targetElem.value = targetCount;
}
function minus(elem){
    let targetElem = elem.parentNode.nextElementSibling.childNodes[0];
    let targetCount = parseInt(targetElem.value);
    if (targetCount > 1) {
        targetCount--;
        targetElem.value = targetCount;
    }
}
```

```html
<c:forEach var = "row" items = "${result.rows}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value = "${row.gift_code}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value = "£${row.price}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value = "${row.stock}"/></td>
            <td><div id="outer">
                <div><button type="button" name="button"onclick="minus(this)"><img src="minus.jpg" alt="minus"/></button></div>
                <div><input type="text" name="name" value="1" size="10" id="count1"></div>
                <div><button type="button" name="button"onclick="plus(this)"><img src="plus.jpg" alt="plus"/></button></div>
                
                                <div><button type="button" name="button"onclick="minus(this)"><img src="minus.jpg" alt="minus"/></button></div>
                <div><input type="text" name="name" value="1" size="10" id="count2"></div>
                <div><button type="button" name="button"onclick="plus(this)"><img src="plus.jpg" alt="plus"/></button></div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form action="order.jsp" method="GET">
                    <input type = "hidden" name = "gift_code"
                           value = "${row.gift_code}" />
                    <input type = "hidden" name = "price"
                           value = "${row.price}" />
                    <input type = "submit" value = "Add to giftlist" />
                    <input type = "hidden" name = "stock"
                           value = "${row.stock}" />

                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </c:forEach>
```

Note the added parameters to the function and the way I use the element the corresponding input. If you have any questions on how this works. Feel free to ask.

Comment: thanks @NTR I used your example and this worked for me. However, seeing as there will be multiple rows due to multiple products in the database which I am using, what way should I go about tackling the issue of same variable names. In your example I can see a different variable is required for each row but I'm unsure how this would be done if the amount of products in the database varies. 2 variables for 2 products makes sense, but when there are tens or hundreds, I'm assuming you wouldn't manually create each variable. Hopefully I explained my question well

Comment: I just lost electricity at my home so I can't verify my idea but instead of using the id you could get the currect element and find the input of that button with it. So in minus and plus function instead of getting the id you could send "this". In your function "this" will be the button pressed. Use that element and in minus get the nextSibling and in plus get the prevousSibling. This.nextSibling

Comment: I tried with document.activeElement to get the current element but now I'm back to the initial problem of my buttons not working so I know there is at least one error with what I attempted. Unless I misunderstood what you was suggesting

Comment: @sh.learner sorry for the delay! I edited my answer so it works without specifying the ID.

Comment: Thank you @NTR, that helped greatly. Appreciate your help and explanations